# when a condition is validated and a label is displayed on the chart, how can it display this label when the bar closes

Tags: pine-script-v5

In an indicator, when a condition is validated and a label is displayed on the chart, how can it display this label when the bar closes or when the new bar opens?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for this function
[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_barstate{dot}islastconfirmedhistory](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_barstate%7Bdot%7Dislastconfirmedhistory)

**Usage**

```
if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    // label.new(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, after reading and after having tested it seems that (barstate.islastconfirmedhistory) does not allow to wait for the close of the candle to display a signal

Comment: you should share your script so that we can help you more precisely.
Your question is too broad